# Forcing hardware acceleration

Tags: .net, wpf, graphics

I just made a benchmark-test in which I continued to add polygons to a canvas and having a dispatchertimer updating each polygons position randomly each pass. I did this until I measured an fps below 30fps. I noticed something, the benchmark doesnt seem to use the GPU. I have rendercapability 2, but I get the same result when turning of Hardware acceleration using the avalon.graphics registret. To me this seems that even if I have rendercapability 2 and a good GPU, wpf still chooses software rendering for an ItemsControl with canvas container and an observablecollection with Polygons as children. (I get around 3500 polygons added before going below 30fps). Is there something I dont understand here? Do I have to use some other shape or rendering-loop to utilize the graphics-hardware?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check with a profiler to be sure, but I suspect the bulk of your overhead is in the code filling the vector graphics buffer rather than the actual rasterization (the part that the hardware helps with.)  You might get a better idea of the rasterization overhead if you don't try to move the polygons, but just rather keep adding new ones.

That said, you may be running into another problem with using an ItemsControl.  Even though the container is a Canvas, the Polygon objects don't get added to the Canvas directly.  The ItemsControl instead creates a container object to host each Polygon and adds that container object to the Canvas.  This means you have another layer of objects participating in the measure/arrange/render passes.

Further, the Polygon class is actually a UIControl, which is a relatively 'heavy' class.  In particular, it allows for UI interactivity, which has a ton of infrastructure involved for mouse events, focus, and of course the whole general DependencyObject infrastructure.  It's not a good choice for performing rendering of a large number of elements.

If you want to do that, it's probably a good idea to create your own UIElement/FrameworkElement derivative and perform the rendering of all of your polygons in an OnRender override.  This allows you to draw directly to the DrawingContext, bypassing all the heavy machinery described above.  You can still make use of the View/ViewModel pattern, but you'll end up implementing your View class in code rather than XAML.

Comment: Ah I see! Thank you very much, I will investigate this further. Do you know of anyway to have an itemscollection and skip the extra container that gets added for each element? I only want to add the polygon itself. Or maybe some more explicit way of adding them without using wpf-controls

Comment: This was indeed an improvement, now my primitive objects are much faster rendered. Another issue I have with WPF render-pipeline is when I add alot of objects at the same time I use AddRange to my ObservableCollection, however there is still a big freeze-lag at the time when they are added and consecutively when I remove/add single objects, have you experienced this? All my objects are not polygons either but more complex objects made up of lines, polygons, text etc etc.

Comment: The default ObservableCollection doesn't handle AddRange very well; there is a [BulkObservableCollection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd867973.aspx) in the VS SDK but it's not part of the standard BCL.  The simplest option may be to replace the entire collection and raise the property changed on the collection property rather than using ObservableCollection.  ObservableCollection is best used for relatively small collections.

Comment: Alright, replacing the whole Collection each time and raising notifypropertychanged is too consuming it seems. It can contain everything from just 20 to 400 objects that needs rendering. The issue Im seeing with observablecollection is when adding 20-30 objects at the same time. This seems to lock my ui-thread. The polygon-thing really helped clear things up, aswell as trying to trim the visual tree